# How to get the cvs change list for a new file

Tags: version-control, diff, cvs, changelog

As part of my work I've been asked to log the cvs commands for creating the changelists for files I've updated as follows:

```
cvs diff -r 1.172 -r 1.173 ./somefile.php
```

But if the file is newly created for that job, no previous version number exists so I can't compare it to anything.  Ideally I'd like to compare it with an empty file so it shows all lines were added.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the best way I found to do this was to use:

```
cvs annotate -r1.1 ./somefile.php
```

Assuming the 1.1 is the version number of the new file.  It isn't a perfect solution as it displays the added lines in a different format to the diff.

**Update**

However a better solution, which now seems obvious, has just occurred to me.  When creating a new file, first check it in to CVS blank, then check it in again with the code, so I can do something like...

```
cvs diff -r1.1 -r1.2 ./somefile.php
```